# so if we need to setup an auto tests (Appium) of an iPhone app from our Win 10 setup - what are all of our options?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, python-appium, appium-desktop

for Android - we just run the emulator and hook them up

but for iPhone what are our options?

can we also run some iPhone emulator?

or hook up an actual iPhone via USB?

or have our code connect to virtual (or real) MacOS that has an iPhone emulator (connected to by Appium)

or for that matter/similar to above - connect to a 3rd party service that will serve up an emulation for us to test? what are the best services?

are these all the options?

thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference from such point of view between android and iOS.
Yes, you can basically use all of the options. 
The most simple way is to run emulator on your machine and test it. If you have such resources, you can test on real devices (the best way). Since you can run iPhone emulator even on Windows there is no need to run emulator on MAC. 
Regarding 3rd party services, there is an AWS farm that uses real mobile devices, but i have never tried it, i think it is the most expensive way